# Why do I get 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error when trying to create a custom logger (Winston/NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, stack-overflow, winston

I'm trying to understand how to use Winston (NodeJS) by creating a logger with custom levels.

logger.js

```
  var winston = require('winston');

  var custom = {
    levels: {
      debug: 0,
      log  : 1,
      info : 2,
      ok   : 3,
      warn : 4,
      cry  : 5,
      fail : 6
    },
    colors: {
      debug: 'grey',
      log  : 'white',
      info : 'cyan',
      ok   : 'green',
      yay  : 'blue',
      warn : 'yellow',
      cry  : 'magenta',
      fail : 'red'
    }
  };

  var customLogger = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
          new (winston.transports.Console)({ colorize:true, prettyPrint: true, level: 'fail', timestamp:false })
      ],
      levels:custom.levels, colors:custom.colors
  });

module.exports = customLogger;
```

//in includes.js

```
var logger = require('./lib/logger.js');
exports.logger = logger;
```

//in app.js

```
var logger = require('includes').logger
logger.cry("Wah Wah Wah");
```

But everytime I try to include my custom logger and use it I get:

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you requiring your logger in app.js?

Comment: logger = require('includes').logger

Comment: And where are the various files located? I assume ./app.js and ./lib/logger.js, but where is includes.js?

Comment: /app.js  /node_modules/common/lib/logger.js /node_modules/common/includes.js

Comment: There is a similar Winston issue: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing that immediately comes to mind is to include logger.js directly in app.js rather than going through includes.js.

I'd love to help more, but with the files in those locations and nothing else to go on but what you've said, as far as I can tell your app shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. You think it's the way the file paths are included? It works fine actually up until the point where I make the call to log.* then thats when I get the error. In some of the issues I found via google they said that this stack error happens when you have an infinite recursive call. -_-